# Change Currency Sign in Oracle Apex Number Format

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, currency-formatting

When i'm using `FML999G999G999G999G990D00` as my Number Format Mask in Oracle Apex, it shows Value as `$800.00`. I need to Replace `$` with another Currency Sign.

How Could i do this ?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=990848

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the session parameter [NLS_CURRENCY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams143.htm#REFRN10118) to change the currency:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY='EUR';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT to_char(800, 'FML999G999G999G999G990D00') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(800,'FML999G999G999G999G9
---------------------------------
EUR800,00
```

Or with [DBMS_SESSION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sessio.htm#i1010906):

```
SQL> BEGIN dbms_session.set_nls('NLS_CURRENCY', 'GBP'); END;
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT to_char(800, 'FML999G999G999G999G990D00') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(800,'FML999G999G999G999G9
---------------------------------
GBP800,00
```

You can also specify the currency directly with [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions201.htm#SQLRF06130):

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(800, 'FML999G990D00', 'NLS_CURRENCY=''£''') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(800,'FML999G9
---------------------
£800,00
```

Comment: After rebooting the server, do I need to setup this again?

Comment: @Mr.Pichler: The `ALTER SESSION` command is session-specific, which means that its effect will end when you end your connection to the database. This is a client settings by the way, so for most applications, there is a way to make this change more permanent (e.g: the register in windows for SQL*Plus)

Comment: I'm using APEX 5.1 but setting the alter session as above in the global page has no effect. When I look at the debug window the first debug statements set the nls to various values, so my guess is that that is overriding my values. Can't find where that is coming from though and Shared Components, Globalization Attributes does not include the currency. You would think Oracle would make this easier and include it there.